# how to use unquoting , quoting in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

can someone explain to me quoting (' or `) unquoting (,) and @ in scheme, drracket and how to use it? Because in my lessons it is not well explained and the examples are not concrete.

Comment: Read ``Quasiquotation in Lisp`` by A Bawden

Comment: Does this answer your question? [backquote, unquote and unquote-splicing in normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612047/backquote-unquote-and-unquote-splicing-in-normal-functions)

Answer (score 4):

A single quote followed by the written representation of a value
will produce that value:

Example:
'(1 x "foo")
will produce a value that prints as `(1 x "foo")`.

Suppose now that I don't want a literal symbol `x` in the list.
I have a variable `x` in my program, and I want to insert
the value to which `x` is bound.

To mark that I want the value of `x` rather than the symbol `x`,
I insert a comma before `x`:

```
'(1 ,x "foo")
```

It won't work as-is though - I now get a value that has a literal comma as well as a symbol `x`. The problem is that `quote` does not know about the comma convention.

Backtick or `quasiquote` knows about the comma-convention, so that will give the correct result:

```
> `(1 ,x "foo")
(1 3 "foo")          ; if the value of x is 3
```

Read more here:
https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html

Use `,@` instead of plain `,` when you want to insert the elements of a list (note that `,` will insert the list).

Compare:

```
> (define xs '(1 2 3))
> `(a b ,xs c d)
'(a b (1 2 3) c d)
> `(a b ,@xs c d)
'(a b 1 2 3 c d)
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax with the  `` `',@ `` are just simplification for the following:

- `'expression` is the same as `(quote expression)`
- `` `expression `` is the same as `(quasiquote expression)`
- `,expression` is the same as `(unquote expression)`
- `,@expression` is the same as `(unquote-splicing expression)`

the special chars instead of the forms are translated at read time. Eg. the evaluation/scheme system never actually sees the characters, only the forms they are the same as. `unquote` and `unquote-splice` can only be used in a `quasiquote` form. Used outside will signal an error as it doesn't have any meaning.

So here are the examples on how they work:

```
(define a '(1 2 3)) ; a is bound to (1 2 3)

;; standard quote. evalates verbatim to the argument 
'(a ,a)
(quote (a (unquote a)))
; ==> (a (unquote a)) 


;; quasiquote will keep the whole structure except 
;; evaluate and insert unquote parts 
`(a ,a)
(quasiquote (a (unquote a)))
; ==> (a (1 2 3))

;; unqote-splicing expects the unquoted expression to evaluate 
;; to a list such that it can be added as elements in the same 
;; structure as the expression
`(a ,@a)
(quasiquote (a (unquote-splicing a)))
; ==> (a 1 2 3)
```

An yes, a REPL might translate back to the syntax. It will never show it in different ways so if your implementation displays `(quote (quasiquote x))` as  `` `x `` then it will simplify all the other ones as well. How they are printed is implementation dependent.